# Set Default Value of SPFieldNumber through programmatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create number field through code with the following schemaXML. Here, I am able to create field, without default value.

```
cretaedlist.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
   "<Field ID='<Guid>'
           Type='Number' 
           Name='<Name>' 
           StaticName='<Name>' 
           DisplayName='<Name>' 
           Default='0' 
           Decimals='0'
    />");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You can try that method:

```
public SPFieldNumber EnsureIntegerField(SPList list, string internalName, string displayName, string description, bool required, bool includeInDefaultView, int? defaultValue)
{
    SPFieldNumber field = null;

    // We first ensure the column is not already there
    if (!list.Fields.ContainsField(internalName))
        list.Fields.Add(internalName, SPFieldType.Number, required);

    field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(internalName) as SPFieldNumber;
    field.Title = displayName;
    field.Description = description;
    if (defaultValue.HasValue)
        field.DefaultValue = defaultValue.Value.ToString();
    field.DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.NoDecimal;

    field.Update();

    if (includeInDefaultView)
    {
        SPView view = list.DefaultView;
        if (!view.ViewFields.Exists(internalName))
        {
            view.ViewFields.Add(field);
            view.Update();
        }
    }

    return field;
}
```